# Laravel 5 - Route not available in notFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, request

Currently I'm experiencing an error I find hard to fix. The error concerns the `\Request::route()` returning `NULL` when the `notFoundHttpException` is fired and my custom error view is rendered.

The problem is that my application needs the current route in order to do a variety of things. I think it is "normal" that `..::route()` returns `NULL` since the route does not exists.

This is where I show my custom error view:

```
// App\Exceptions\Handler
return response()->view('layouts.default', [
    'main_content' => view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode())
], $e->getStatusCode());
```

When I call `\Request::route()` inside my view it returns `NULL`.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this in a clean way?

**Edit**

The application I am currently working on is a multi domain system. The route is needed to determine what domain is currently requested.

All routes are wrapped inside one group:

```
Route::group(['domain' => {domain}.{tld}], function()
{
    // Application routes...
}
```

To determine the domain:

```
$domain = \Request::route()->domain;

$tld = \Request::route()->tld;

// Retrieve from database...
```

Yes there are work arounds like:

```
// Url requested: mydomain.com/notexistingpage

$url_parameters = @explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$domain = $url_parameters[0];

$tld = $url_parameters[1];

// Retrieve from database...
```

However I would like to keep using the router to serve the parameters. I'll mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
```

or

```
\Route::getCurrentRoute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working. Like I said the route does not exists so it returns null. I'll update my question to make clear why my application "needs" the route.

Answer (score 0):

A work around could be:

```
// Url requested: mydomain.com/notexistingpage

$url_parameters = @explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$domain = $url_parameters[0];

$tld = $url_parameters[1];

// Retrieve from database...
```